# Inverted exclamation mark gets added in the output written by Google cloud storage

Tags: streamsets

Thank you for the support in advance.

Using streamset pipeline, I am trying to load the MSSQL CDC data using SQL Server CDC Client origin and load into destinations in Google cloud storage and local FS.

While the local FS writes as expected, the file in Google Cloud storages has inverted exclamation mark beginning of the file.

I could not figure out why it happens. Any idea?

```
¡{"header":{"stageCreator":"SQLServerCDCClient_01","sourceId":"cdc.HumanResources_Shift_CT::___$seqval=0000005500002F380008::___$operation=1::___$start_lsn=0000005500002F38000E","stagesPath":"SQLServerCDCClient_01","trackingId":"cdc.HumanResources_Shift_CT::___$seqval=0000005500002F380008::___$operation=1::___$start_lsn=0000005500002F38000E::SQLServerCDCClient_01","previousTrackingId":null,"raw":null,"rawMimeType":null,"errorDataCollectorId":null,"errorPipelineName":null,"errorStage":null,"errorStageLabel":null,"errorCode":null,"errorMessage":null,"errorTimestamp":0,"errorStackTrace":null,"errorJobId":null,"values":{"sdc.operation.type":"2","jdbc.__$seqval.jdbcType":"-2","jdbc.__$start_lsn":"0000005500002F38000E","jdbc.__$operation.jdbcType":"4","jdbc.__$update_mask.jdbcType":"-3","jdbc.cdc.source_name":"Shift","jdbc.tables":"HumanResources_Shift_CT","jdbc.__$seqval":"0000005500002F380008","jdbc.__$update_mask":"1F","jdbc.ShiftID.jdbcType":"-6","jdbc.__$operation":"1","jdbc.StartTime.jdbcType":"92","jdbc.ModifiedDate.jdbcType":"93","jdbc.cdc.source_schema_name":"HumanResources","jdbc.Name.jdbcType":"-9","jdbc.EndTime.jdbcType":"92","jdbc.__$start_lsn.jdbcType":"-2"}},"value":{"type":"LIST_MAP","value":[{"type":"SHORT","value":15,"sqpath":"/ShiftID","dqpath":"/ShiftID"},{"type":"STRING","value":"Full Day Shift","sqpath":"/Name","dqpath":"/Name"},{"type":"TIME","value":38836977,"sqpath":"/StartTime","dqpath":"/StartTime"},{"type":"TIME","value":67636977,"sqpath":"/EndTime","dqpath":"/EndTime"},{"type":"DATETIME","value":1625132836977,"sqpath":"/ModifiedDate","dqpath":"/ModifiedDate"}],"sqpath":"","dqpath":""}}
```

[image]

Configuration in the Google cloud storage stage,
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: How does you Data Format configuration looks like in Google Cloud Storage stage?
Which settings do you have there?

Comment: @AndreyE, I have updated my question with what you were asking for.

Comment: Thanks, looking at it.

Do you really need the record header data to be written as well?
Otherwise you could use JSON as a format, it doesn't seem to have this problem.

Comment: Well, the record header gives us lot of information when we load the cdc data into target database. For example timestamp, offset, operation(update/delete/insert) would help us to perform many other actions.